# How to distinguish ERC20 and ERC721?

Tags: ethereum

How can I differentiate between ERC20 and ERC721? without checking Etherscan

Answer (score 3):

ERC20 Token-Transfer Event and ERC721 Token-Transfer Event is differentiated by the number of topics. ERC20 transfer Event's is 3 but ERC721's is 4. I distinguished that way.Check it out on Etherscan.
Thanks

Comment: both have 3 parameters (address, address, uint256) as per specifications https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-20 and https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-721

Comment: Thanks for comment. According to the official documentation, three parameters are correct for both standards. What I talked about was that when viewing the event log on etherscan, in the case of the ERC20 token transfer event, the last value parameter was not included as a topic but was displayed in the data, so the number of topics should be 4 ERC721 and 3 ERC20. Saying it's a parameter is an obvious error. Thanks for the good point.